# How does HashMap get() compare keys?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

What is the mechanism by which HashMap get() functions?

If I have an InetSocketAddress as my key, will a lookup return a value with a key having the same InetAddress and the same port as get()s parameter?

Comment: Could you please provide an example so we can better establish what exactly you want to achieve? Even a sudo I/O would suffice.

Comment: I have the feeling I could probably answer this question if only I could understand what you are talking about.

Comment: What is the key, and is the value in your `HashMap`? Both are generic types in the `Map` interface. So I can't tell what you are asking...

Comment: Just a wild guess since I also don't understand the question, but sounds like maybe you'd be interested in Guava's [equivalence wrapper](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.Wrapper.html)?

Comment: Sorry I'll update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Map#get()` method compares whether two objects are `equals()`. [In the case of an `InetSocketAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#equals-java.lang.Object-),

> Compares this object against the specified object. The result is `true` if and only if the argument is not `null` and it represents the same address as this object.
>
> Two instances of `InetSocketAddress` represent the same address if both the `InetAddress`es (or hostnames if it is unresolved) and port numbers are equal. If both addresses are unresolved, then the hostname and the port number are compared. Note: Hostnames are case insensitive. e.g. "FooBar" and "foobar" are considered equal.

Thus, you should be able to have a `Map<InetSocketAddress,Foo>` that looks up information about a particular connection.